# Handling inserts into a database with varying and large number of columns in golang

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

So I have golang program that reads a JSON off a kafka queue, makes it into normal flat syntax and pushes to a database table. The table is has (200+) columns, if the data doesn't contain a column, a null should be inserted.

Currently I can do that by forming the INSERT statement manually(with the present fields), problem comes with database arguments, how do I pass the argument to `db.Query` ?

The database to be populated is postgresql.

Comment: What do you mean by "database arguments"? Could you give a minimal example of what such a query looks like including the database arguments?

Comment: @csm can you check the answer below, it has exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming column values will default to null if not set, here's one approach.

Create a map of column names to interface{} values:

```
args := make(map[string]interface{})
```

Set the column values you're interested in:

```
args["col_x"] = . . . 
args["col_y"] = . . .
```

Prepare the sql statement:

```
sql = "insert into tab ( xxx ) values ( yyy )"
```

where xxx is the list of column names, and yyy is the list of value replacement characters, one for each value, specific to the database, eg, ?

Finally execute the query, expanding args as a variadic parameter:

```
db.Exec(sql, args...)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for, can we use varargs like this on all functions that have multiple arguments like this in golang ?

Comment: The function must be declared to accept variadic parameters, as [DB.Query](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) does. See also the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters). Also [have a play](https://play.golang.org/p/Xk9tqeCkit).

Comment: Glad to hear. Also, use [db.Exec](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec) for inserts and updates, not db.Query. Use db.Query when the query returns rows. I just noticed now and edited the answer.